String replacement in makefile
I have a small snippet to replace kvvm60 to main in a directory path where it's not working as expected.
hello:= /home/kvvm60/foo/bar

$(info inside hello $(hello))

TEST := $(patsubst %kvvm60%,%main%,$(hello))

$(info test is $(TEST))

Output:-
inside hello /home/kvvm60/foo/bar
test is /home/kvvm60/foo/bar
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

Am i missing something

Only ONE (the first) % is treated as wildcard

If there is only one kvvm60 you can try TEST := $(subst kvvm60,main,$(hello)).
